# how do i write ng-repeat for this in my html code

Tags: angularjs

```
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
$scope.inputs=[
{name:a[i],value:b[i]} 
];

}
```

this is my Javascript code i want to know how to write (ng-repeat) for arrays

Comment: we write ng-repeat in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS is invalid, will produce length 1 array. Replace it with this:

```
$scope.inputs=[];
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){// be sure that a.length >=b.length
   $scope.inputs.push({name:a[i],value:b[i]}); // push will add new entry to your inputs array.
}
```

The  you can use it in ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in inputs"> {{entry.name}} : {{entry.value}} </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't write loops surrounding a global variable. You leave the variable by itself and then you call the loop. Later you just use the global variable in the html code.

I made a cool snippet so you understand how it works:

```js
angular.module('demo', [])

.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.inputs = [];

  var a = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']; 
  var b = [133,233,456];

  //this code has to be called somewhere else. It might be part of a function.
  for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++){
    $scope.inputs.push( {name:a[i],value:b[i]} );
  }
  
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in inputs">
                <input ng-model="item.name"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
        
        <!--This is only to display the content of $scope.inputs -->
        <pre>{{inputs | json}}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array in your controller, with a scope that is visible in your html

```
angular.module('appName').controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl);

function mainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.inputs = [
        key: value,
        ...
    ];
}
```

In your html you would use `ng-repeat` within the scope of the controller. You can use the `ng-repeat` directive on several different html tags, such as `<ul>` lists, a `div`, select dropdowns and more

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
     <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="item in inputs">{{item.key}} <!-- Prints 'value' --></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```